# trying to implement polymorphism with go interfaces

Tags: go, go-interface, libchan

I'm trying to create a layer on top of a third party library, in this case [libchan](https://github.com/docker/libchan/). Here's an interface I've defined:

```
type ReceiverStream interface {
    Receive(msg interface{}) error
}

type InboundTransport interface {
    WaitReceiveChannel() (ReceiverStream, error)
}
```

The `InboundTransport` is meant to be a stand-in for a type `Transport`:

```
// libchan.go
type Transport interface {
    // NewSendChannel creates and returns a new send channel.  The receive
    // end will get picked up on the remote end of the transport through
    // the remote calling WaitReceiveChannel.
    NewSendChannel() (Sender, error)

    // WaitReceiveChannel waits for a new channel be created by the
    // remote end of the transport calling NewSendChannel.
    WaitReceiveChannel() (Receiver, error)
}
```

Just for context, this is the `libchan.Receiver` definition (please note that it matches my `ReceiverStream`:

```
// libchan.go
type Receiver interface {
    // Receive receives a message sent across the channel from
    // a sender on the other side of the underlying transport.
    // Receive is expected to receive the same object that was
    // sent by the Sender, any differences between the
    // receive and send type should be handled carefully.  It is
    // up to the application to determine type compatibility, if
    // the receive object is incompatible, Receiver will
    // throw an error.
    Receive(message interface{}) error
}
```

The `Transport` is returned by the libchan library [here](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/spdy/session.go#L62):

```
// libchan/session.go:62
func NewTransport(provider StreamProvider) libchan.Transport {
...
}
```

Since `libchan.Transport` and `InboundTransport` share a `WaitReceiveChannel() (ReceiverStream, error)` method, I figured I should be able to sub one for the other, like so:

```
func (ln SpdyListener) Accept(addr string) InboundTransport {
    var listener net.Listener
    var err error
    listener, err = net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    p, err := spdy.NewSpdyStreamProvider(c, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return spdy.NewTransport(p)
}
```

But I get an error:

```
cannot use spdy.NewTransport(p) (type libchan.Transport) as type InboundTransport in return argument:
    libchan.Transport does not implement InboundTransport (wrong type for WaitReceiveChannel method)
        have WaitReceiveChannel() (libchan.Receiver, error)
        want WaitReceiveChannel() (ReceiverStream, error)
```

I assume that what this error means is that a type of `ReceiverStream` does not match `libchan.Receiver`, but I thought that golang interfaces were implicit, meaning that as long as the return type implements the same methods as the expected interface, it would pass compilation. Is there anything I can change so that I can superimpose a self-defined interface onto one returned by a third part library?

TLDR: A third party lib is returning an object of interface `Transport`. The `Transport` interface specifies a method `WaitReceiveChannel()`. I have a self-defined interface `InboundTransport` that also specifies `WaitReceiveChannel()`. The third-party method I'm calling returns an object that implements `Transport` by way of method `WaitReceiveChannel()`. I assumed that it would also implement `InboundTransport` since the latter also specifies a `WaitReceiveChannel()` of the same type. This isn't working. Why not?

Answer (score 4):

As you already know interfaces in Go are satisfied implicitly.

But, as the error states,

```
WaitReceiveChannel() (libchan.Receiver, error)
```

and

```
WaitReceiveChannel() (ReceiverStream, error)
```

are two different *method types*, resulting in `libchan.Transport` not implicitly implementing `InboundTransport`.

To work around this you have to write a thin wrapper around `libchan.Transport` that implements the `InboundTransport` properly.

```
type TransportWrapper struct {
    t *libchan.Transport
}

func (w *TransportWrapper) WaitReceiveChannel() (Receiver, error) {
    return w.t.WaitReceiveChannel()
}

// ...

func (ln SpdyListener) Accept(addr string) InboundTransport {
    var listener net.Listener
    var err error
    listener, err = net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    p, err := spdy.NewSpdyStreamProvider(c, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return &TransportWrapper{spdy.NewTransport(p)}
}
```