# Implement an interface for the return type of the Query method of the sql.DB

Tags: go

I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/pieohpah/mocking-database-in-go-55bo) to mock the database connection. But when I try to go further and implement an interface for the return type of the Query method I get an error.

Here is the working version that **doesn't** work for the `MockDB` but works for `main`:

```golang
// The DB interface
type SQLDB interface {
    Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
}

type MockDB struct {
    // ...
}

func (m *MockDB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (SQLRows, error) {
    // var row MockRows
    // ...
    return rows, nil
}

// #################################

// The Rows interface
type SQLRows interface {
    Next() bool
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}

type MockRows struct {
    // ...
}

func (m *MockRows) Next() bool {
    // ...
    return true
}

func (m *MockRows) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error {
    // ...
    return nil
}


// #################################

// Usage

func GetStuff(db SQLDB) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    results := db.Query("query")
    // ...
    return results, nil
}

// #################################

// Main
var db SQLDB
func main() {
    db = sql.Open("driver", "uri")
    results := GetResult(db)
}

// #################################

// Test
func TestGetStuff(t *testing.T) {
    mockDB = new(MockDB)
    results := GetResult(mockDB)
    // ...
}
```

This works for main, but not for test and I get the following error when running tests:

```
*MockDB does not implement SQLDB (wrong type for Query method)
    have Query(string, ...interface {}) (SQLRows, error)
    want Query(string, ...interface {}) (*sql.Rows, error)
```

Here is the version that **works** for the `MockDB` but doesn't for `main`:

```golang
// The DB interface
type SQLDB interface {
    Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (SQLRows, error)
}

type MockDB struct {
    // ...
}

func (m *MockDB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (SQLRows, error) { // <<<<<< Changed
    // var row MockRows
    // ...
    return rows, nil
}

// #################################

// The Rows interface
type SQLRows interface {
    Next() bool
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}

type MockRows struct {
    // ...
}

func (m *MockRows) Next() bool {
    // ...
    return true
}

func (m *MockRows) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error {
    // ...
    return nil
}


// #################################

// Usage

func GetStuff(db SQLDB) (SQLRows, error) { // <<<<<< Changed
    results := db.Query("query")
    // ...
    return results, nil
}

// #################################

// Main
var db SQLDB
func main() {
    db = sql.Open("driver", "uri")
    results := GetResult(db)
}

// #################################

// Test
func TestGetStuff(t *testing.T) {
    mockDB = new(MockDB)
    results := GetResult(mockDB)
    // ...
}
```

And here is the error:

```
 *sql.DB does not implement SQLDB (wrong type for Query method)
        have Query(string, ...interface {}) (*sql.Rows, error)
        want Query(string, ...interface {}) (SQLRows, error)
```

How can I make it work for both? Or It's just can't be done at all?

Comment: By making both return the same type, which, if you want to be able to mock it, *must* be the interface type. `*sql.Rows` is *not* an interface type.

Comment: In case it is not obvious from the above, you can't use `*sql.DB` as `SQLDB` because `*sql.DB` does not implement the `SQLDB` interface. What you can do however is to wrap `*sql.DB` in a thin wrapper that implements `SQLDB` and whose implementation just delegates the call to the wrapped `*sql.DB`.

Comment: @XO39, Golang provides special interface for database developers, you should follow and use: https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/05.1.html

Comment: Try taking a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51008556/965900 it provides more info on the wrapper technique.

Comment: @mkopriva What about the connection itself, couldn't figure out how to handle/pass it, it's more complex than it sounds, any ideas?

Comment: @DanielHornik I am hoping to find an easier way other than implementing the whole thing!

Comment: @XO39 as I said you should wrap the connection `*sql.DB` in a thin wrapper that implements the interface `SQLDB`, it's as simple as that, really.

Comment: @XO39 https://play.golang.org/p/rIH8yGeX2sG

Comment: @mkopriva OK, I was wrapping the wrong interface and I was getting odd errors and results, after the "*... it's simple as that, really*" comment I cleaned up some code and paid more attention and it just worked. Thanks. If you wish you can post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @XO39 i've added the answer. Please keep in mind that the method [`(*sql.Rows).Close()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) MUST be invoked once you're done with the rows or else you'll leak connections and your program will eventually crash. So you need to expose it through the `SQLRows` interface and invoke it manually or ensure that it is invoked in some other way, whatever that may be.

Comment: @mkopriva I have  `defer rows.Close()` in the original code inside the method that operate on the rows. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to wrap `*sql.DB` in a thin wrapper that implements `SQLDB` and whose implementation just delegates the call to the wrapped `*sql.DB`.

```
type dbwrapper struct{ db *sql.DB }

func (w *dbwrapper) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (SQLRows, error) {
    return w.db.Query(query, args...) // delegate
}
```

Now instead of using `*sql.DB` directly you wrap it in the `dbwrapper` which then can be used as the `SQLDB` interface.

```
func GetStuff(db SQLDB) (SQLRows, error) {
    // ...
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("driver", "uri")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    w := &dbwrapper{db}
    rows, err := GetStuff(w) // will compile
    // ...
}
```